# C++: Class scope and definition order

Tags: c++, class, scope

I am having trouble figuring a way around this one problem. Essentially, I have a node that has input and output ports that connect to other nodes. The ports have different attributes that I would like to group together in a class. The code I have now is

```
class Node
{
 private:
    std::vector<Port*> m_Input; 
    std::vector<Port*> m_Output; 
...
};

class Port
{
 private:
    Node* m_Connection;
    std::string m_PortName;
 ...
}
```

`

The error is when trying to compile Port.cpp, the include file for Node says that Port is not declared. Is there a way to declare the class globally so that it can be see by Port. Something like having a function definition at the top. Thanks

Comment: `class Port;` / `class Node;`

Comment: just forward declare `class Port;` before defining `Node`

Comment: Or `class Node* m_Connection;`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
class Port;

class Node
{
 private:
    std::vector<Port*> m_Input; 
    std::vector<Port*> m_Output; 
...
};

class Port
{
 private:
    Node* m_Connection;
    std::string m_PortName;
 ...
}
```